# SQL: calculate sum from IDs and 2 (or more) different tables

Tags: sql, join, sum

I think an example is worth a thousand words.

Table: CONTINENTS:

```
id | continent
---+----------
 1 | Africa
 2 | America
 3 | Asia
 4 | Europe
 5 | Oceania
```

Table: COUNTRIES

```
id | countries      | population | continent_id
---+----------------+------------+-------------
 1 | Australia      |   24500000 | 5
 2 | Brazil         |  209300000 | 2
 3 | Canada         |   36600000 | 2
 4 | France         |   65000000 | 4
 5 | Germany        |   82100000 | 4
 6 | Italy          |   59400000 | 4
 7 | Japan          |  127500000 | 3
 8 | South Africa   |   56700000 | 1
 9 | South Korea    |   51000000 | 3
10 | United Kingdom |   66200000 | 4
11 | United States  |  324500000 | 2
```

And the result I'd like:

```
id | continent | continent_population
---+-----------+---------------------
 1 | Africa    |             56700000
 2 | America   |            570400000
 3 | Asia      |            178500000
 4 | Europe    |            272700000
 5 | Oceania   |             24500000
```

So yes, I'd like the population of each continent to be the result of the sum of countries, which are in another table. I've tried a lot of queries but nothing worked.

Also, this title probably sucks but I wasn't sure how to word it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, JOINing the two tables continent_id to id, then summing the population, and grouping by the continent:

```
SELECT
CONTINENTS.id,
CONTINENTS.continent,
SUM(COUNTRIES.population) as continent_population
FROM CONTINENTS
LEFT JOIN COUNTRIES ON COUNTRIES.continent_id=CONTINENTS.id
GROUP BY CONTINENTS.id, CONTINENTS.continent
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @rp17 glad it worked for you :)